Lower inductors parasitic capacitance
Is it possible to lower inductors parasitic capacitance (between turns) by winding it with shielded wire and grounding the shield (probably from the one side)? What techniques can also be implemented to achieve the same goal?

A coil of shielded wire is a transformer. The shield as secondary winding then has the parasitic capacitance.

1)
Use multi-section bobbin and wind every section in once.
So in case of 4 section bobbin wind just 1,2,3,4 , not a 1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1 or 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4.

Source of image: www.mycoiltech.com
It doesn’t decrease the  interwinding capacity much (in single layer), but decreases the capacity between layers, that is usually more important in high voltage apps, comparing to typical multilayer winding.
2)
There is an option to wind zigzag, turns in small angle, layers in opposite angles, so turns doesn’t lay near each other, but it decreases the stacking factor and increases leakage inductance.

Winding the inductor with grounded shielded wire would possibly reduce the parasitic capacitance between turns, but you would increase the parasitic capacitance to ground astronomically. That is not what you want to do.
You can decrease the interwinding capacitance other ways:

Decrease the wire gauge. Decreasing the wire gauge reduces the area which formes the parasitic capacity. Depending on your current requirements you might need to wind multiple smaller wires in parallel.

Increase the distance between windings. The distance also decreases the capacitance. If you leave more space between the windings you will achieve lower parasitic capacitance.



Is parasitic capacitance to ground always an issue, if, for example, the inductor is a part of an LC prefilter for an LDO?

It will affect the filter transfer function. There will be some added resonancies at higher frequencies. It will also affect the efficiency. If you are using it as a prefilter for LDO, I would consider using a ferrite bead instead. You might achieve what you want without any potential instabilities.

Could you explain (1) in more detail? For example, if using finer wire, and one assumes constant pitch, this might have the desired effect; but using multiple strands has the same problem as using solid wire: it takes up more space, and thus the capacitance between turns, or to surroundings, is high (distance to surroundings is shorter, capacitive area higher).

@TimWilliams You need to keep the paralel strands close to each other and turns further apart to achieve lower interwinding capacitance. I've seen it done several ways. One could wind the strands in one layer, which as you suggested would increase the area, but that might not be a problem, depending on your requirements. Other times you wind the wires in triplets, when 2 strands form a base and one is imposed on top, that has lower effect on decresing the capacitance, but reduces the size. Always a decision in play. No one size fits all.
